# Вопрос об оптимальности (парсинг строки вида "R142C1543:R18999C24568")

Tags: алгоритм, c++

В итерационной процедуре (С++) из строки wchar_t вида "R142C1543:R18999C24568" необходимо "выкусить" числовые данные:

long RS=142
   long RE=18999
   long CS=1543
   long CE=24568

Учитывая, что это надо сделать максимально эффективно, какие варианты вы можете предложить!? (причём количество разрядов чисел постоянно меняется)

Comment: Разделители собственно говоря R---C---:R---C---Конец строки

Comment: Дето я это видел :) Не codeforges случайно ? )

Comment: Не знаю что такое codeforges! Это одна из конструкций xltable

Comment: Активность то что нужно! Спасибо всем участникам и сайту! До некоторых реализаций я бы с ходу не дошёл! Здорово, что есть пиплы которык "Шарят в теме", Россия рулит! Но тем не менее вопрос об оптимальном решении(в плане быстродействия) так и не решён! Как мне кажется (интуитивно :)) самым оптимальным является алгоритм GLAGOLA!?

Comment: привели 3 решения:
1. использовать функцию swscanf;
2. самописный автомат, тот что я приводил;
3. решение от gecube в стиле C++;
Если за критерий оценки брать кол-во раз, которое пробегаем по строке то:
1. не смог найти код функции swscanf;
2. 1 пробег по строке;
3. 3 (replace) + 1 (считывание) = 4 пробега по строке;
вроде бы так)

Comment: А вот теперь объясните мне - зачем писать на плюснутых сях как на обычных си? Код от GLAGOLA действительно будет эффективнее - нет созданий объектов классов и т.п. Но вот поддерживать его сложнее. И как он поведет себя в случае некорректных данных на входе - вопрос.<p>
PS: C++ вариант улучшил.

Comment: Насчет некорректный данных - абсолютно согласен, segfault'a не избежать. А вот насчет того, что "зачем писать на плюснутых сях как на обычных си?" хочу отметить, что мой код - простой,не без извращенный правда, автомат(ПОЧТИ базовый алгоритм). Да,и кто Вам сказал, что если пишешь на C++, то надо везде использовать классы? Насчет поддержки, мне кажется, что стоит написать небольшую доку по поводу того какие данные должны быть на входе, какие на выходе и пользоваться им как черным ящиком, а в последствии, в случае каких-либо перемен, просто выбросить (кода мало - не жалко) его и написать заново

Comment: Кстати, если Вы перешли на лямбды, то почему бы в ней же не разбирать числа - тогда добьетесь всего одного прохода, но ИМХО читаемость это явно не улучшит.

Comment: GLAGOLA, согласен, можно написать простую ф-цую, задокументировать ее и использовать как черный ящик. Главное - чтоб потом ее можно было удобно интегрировать в код. У меня, например, на плюснутых Цэ, везде используется string или более серьезные типы для хранения строк. Понятно, что стандартная ф-ция с входом в виде char\* и/или wchar_t\* будет работать не супер. А конвертировать туда-сюда - не очень. Поэтому вариант с string + stringstream более универсален. С другой стороны, я нигде не утверждал, что знаю С++. Чем больше копаешь его - тем многограннее становится увиденная картина.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Гляньте в сторону  [swscanf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/swscanf.html)

Можно было бы написать небольшой парсер для данной строки, чтобы не использовать сторонние библиотеки, однако загвоздка в типе wchar_t судя по [википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB) его размер сильно зависит от компилятора. Но если удастся все-таки за что-то зацепиться можно было бы написать небольшую функцию, по типу этой (сейчас она сделана для char):

```
int main ()
{
    wchar_t * input = (wchar_t *)L"R142C1543:R18999C24568";

    struct {
        long RS;
        long CS;
        long RE;
        long CE;
    } result = {0, 0, 0, 0};

    long * current = (long *)&result;

    while (*++input)
    {
        switch (*input)
        {
            case L':' : input++;
            case L'C' : current++;
                        break;

            default   : *current = *current*10 + (*input - L'0');
        }
    }

    printf("RS = %ld\n", result.RS);
    printf("CS = %ld\n", result.CS);
    printf("RE = %ld\n", result.RE);
    printf("CE = %ld\n", result.CE);
}
```

---

P.S. немного модифицировал код, чтобы работало с wchar_t, спасибо за подсказку [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp).

P.S.S. L-ки перед символами ':', 'C', '0' вроде не обязательно ставить (по крайне мере работает как с ними так и без них), но я на всякий пожарный поставил.

Comment: Не вижу смысле его добавлять: мы точно знаем, что строка начинается с R, также мы точно знаем, что после двоеточия идет R, следовательно, вводить проверку на R не имеет смысла.

Comment: мы с вами спорим по данному поводу в другом топике ;) 

за счет input++ в case ':' он перепрыгнет букву R.

Comment: Красиво! Не пойму что делает *input - '0'

Comment: Превращает символ в соответствующее число. Фишка в том, что коды цифр 0...9 идут последовательно в таблице символов. Следовательно, вычитая значение '0' (код символа 0), мы получим саму цифру :-)

Comment: Очень оригинально!

Comment: Только input д.б. не char * , а wchar_t * , о размере wchar_t не беспокойтесь, адресная арифметика сработает нормально. Если ничего, кроме R,C, двоеточия и цифр в строке нет, то работать будет. Иначе надо менять код в default , по крайней мере. Размер wchar_t (если требуется) даст sizeof, например sizeof (*input) или sizeof (wchar_t).

Comment: Только в while (*input++), нужно использовать префиксный инкремент а не постфиксный! while (*++input)

Answer (score 1):

```
// C++ STYLE !!!
using namespace std;

...

string x("R142C1543:R18999C24568");
replace(x.begin(), x.end(), 'R', ' '); // удалим все лишние символы :-)
replace(x.begin(), x.end(), 'C', ' ');
replace(x.begin(), x.end(), ':', ' ');

// более оптимальным является использование replace_if с lambda
// это уменьшает кол-во проходов по строчке для замены с ТРЕХ до ОДНОГО 
/*
replace_if(x.begin(), x.end(), [] (const char ch) -> bool {return (!isdigit (ch)); }, ' ');
// можно и без лямбды
// replace_if (x.begin(), x.end(), not1(ptr_fun(isdigit)), ' ');

*/
stringstream y(x);

long RS;    long CS;    long RE;    long CE;

y>>RS>>CS>>RE>>CE; // считаем числа за раз. Если ошиблись - запишет 0.
// итого - по строчке минимум пройдемся два раза - для замены, для считывания.
```

Код НЕ ПРОВЕРЯЛ.

Плюсы плюсатого кода:

1. Код короткий и самоочевидный (ну, разве кроме лямбды).
2. Можно легко прикрутить блоки обработки ошибок try-catch и никаких segfault'ов
3. При наличии хорошего компилятора - код может соптимизироваться в нечто не сильно хуже, чем изначально простой вариант С кода.

Comment: А на >> если не цифра и не SPACE не зациклится ?

Comment: Почему должен зациклиться? Во-первых, по условию задачи формат исходной строки задан конкретно. Во-вторых, при неудаче cin и stringstream возвращают ноль и вообще должны генерировать исключение. В третьих, наверняка можно оптимизировать replace'ы и/или указать символы-разделители для разбиения stringstream.

Comment: Но тогда в последней итерации цикла указатель будет направлен на нуль символ, а это приведёт к тому, что в  CE будут записаны не верные данные!

Comment: хм, точно...косяк поправил. К ответу может быть не более 8 комментов.

Comment: Продолжу здесь, to @gecube абсолютно согласен, если проект весь на C++, то данная функция будет выбиваться из общего фона, но ведь можно обертку написать (вплоть до макроса). А для конвертации string -> char* вроде есть метод string::c_str(), я даже подозреваю, что там вовсе не конвертация, а просто ссылка на внутреннюю структуру (не проверял)

Comment: @gecube я сам сторонник C++ и более высокоуровневых языков, но когда встает вопрос о производительности (к тому же формат входных данных строго задан) и нет желания бросаться в крайности (ассемблер), то Си, на мой взгляд, лучший вариант.