# Проверка ввода формата ввода данных

Tags: c++

Зашел в тупик: не могу сообразить, как реализовать проверку ввода данных. Пишу на Win32 API C++. Пользователь вводит последовательности чисел такого формата: (a1, ..., an) ...(z1, ..., zn). Все? что он ввел? считываю в переменную cI[buf]. Проверку организовал тока самих вводимых символов. Но вот как организовать проверку порядка вводимых данных, не могу сообразить. К примеру, что бы такое ()()(0) не прошло, ну и если скобки попутать или какая-нибудь лишняя. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

> мне нужно проверить что он ввел так как надо

Тогда пробегаете по строчке слева направо. Анализируете каждый символ. Т.о. Вы реализуете механизм автомата. Состояние которого изменяется при переходе к каждому новому символу. Для этого придется завести некоторое кол-во флаговых переменных и делать switch по каждому символу. Выглядеть будет примерно [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/15797/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0-r142c1543-r18999c24568#15821).

Comment: программа с графическим интерфейсом, данные считываю в переменную char cI[BUF_SIZE];

Comment: Т.е. ввели строчку и только после этого проверяем данные?

Comment: да пользователь вводит нажимает "ок" и мне нужно проверить что он ввел так как надо...

Comment: идею примерно понял спасибо.Ссылка у меня не работает(( если не сложно то можете поправить?

Comment: поправил.